# CSS to display table row headers above data cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

Suppose I have a table like this on an HTML page, with a purple border around the `th` cells and a green border around the `td` cells:

[image: screenshot of simple table]

Some code that produces this (the CSS for the `view-small` class isn't in use in the above display but it's about to be explained):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Table Transformation</title>
    
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <style>
    body { font-family: "Opens Sans", sans-serif; }
    
    td { border: 1px solid green; }
    th { border: 1px solid purple; }
    
    .view-small table { display: block; width: 100%; }
    .view-small tbody { display: block; }
    .view-small tr { display: block; width: 100%; margin: 2em auto; position; relative; }
    .view-small th { display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }
    .view-small td { display: inline-block; height: 1em; width: 30%; transform: translateY(1.5em); }
    
    </style>
</head>    
    <body class="">
        <h1>Table Example</h1>
        
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Numbers</th>
                <td>One</td>
                <td>Two</td>
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Countries</th>
                <td>Canada</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
                <td>Guatemala</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Planets</th>
                <td>Mars</td>
                <td>Jupiter</td>
                <td>Saturn</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <p>End of test</p>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

We were thinking that for smaller devices, it would be neat if we could save horizontal space by display each row header over its corresponding data cells. If I set `class="view-small"` in the body tag in the code above, I get this in Chrome on Windows and pretty much the same thing in Firefox and IE11:

[image: screenshot of table with row header displayed above data cells from the same row]

This demonstrates what I'm going for. What I'd really like to achieve includes having the data cells take up the horizontal space that the full row would have occupied. In the above code, I have their width set artificially to 30%, but that isn't ideal!

I'm going to tinker with this some more, but I thought I'd see whether anyone else has tried anything like this or seen a solution somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the width and margin values. The total value of width (including both horizontal margins) should be around 33%. These '3' after dot make it more precise.

```css
div{
  width: 30.3333333333%;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hi. I don't have any divs to apply this to. Semantically, this is a table (certainly, one that I've created for demo purposes, not the one that I'm going to be creating for real), and the HTML will have table markup. Also, I do want it to have a normal table display when the viewport is above a given width (for which I currently have the view-small class standing in, but I will replace that with a media query).

Comment: It occurred to me that the spacing between the cells is on account of my having line breaks between them in the HTML, which is getting turned into spaces in the browser. I realized I'll have to have the td elements all one line to force them to be adjacent.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you can use table's tags (td,th) instead of it and it should works